# Rigaya's NVEnc encodes file with no video or audio track

Tags: hevc, nvenc

My source video file (1h 30min movie) is playable in both PotPlayer and VLC: h264, 8-bit color and 7755kb/s bitrate.

The NVEnc command I'm using is this:

```
.\nvencc\NVEncC64.exe --avhw -i "input.mkv" --codec hevc --preset quality --bframes 4 --ref 7 --cu-max 32 --cu-min 8 --output-depth 10 --audio-copy --sub-copy -o "output.mkv"
```

Encoding works fine (I believe):

```
NVEncC (x64) 5.26 (r1786) by rigaya, Jan 31 2021 09:23:04 (VC 1928/Win/avx2)
OS Version     Windows 10 x64 (19042)
CPU            AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor [3.79GHz] (6C/12T)
GPU            #0: GeForce GTX 1660 (1408 cores, 1830 MHz)[PCIe3x16][457.51]
NVENC / CUDA   NVENC API 11.0, CUDA 11.1, schedule mode: auto
Input Buffers  CUDA, 21 frames
Input Info     avcuvid: H.264/AVC, 1920x800, 24000/1001 fps
AVSync         vfr
Vpp Filters    cspconv(nv12 -> p010)
Output Info    H.265/HEVC main10 @ Level auto
               1920x800p 1:1 23.976fps (24000/1001fps)
               avwriter: hevc, eac3, subtitle#1 => matroska
Encoder Preset quality
Rate Control   CQP  I:20  P:23  B:25
Lookahead      off
GOP length     240 frames
B frames       4 frames [ref mode: disabled]
Ref frames     7 frames, MultiRef L0:auto L1:auto
AQ             off
CU max / min   32 / 8
Others         mv:auto

encoded 142592 frames, 219.97 fps, 1549.90 kbps, 1098.83 MB
encode time 0:10:48, CPU: 8.7%, GPU: 5.2%, VE: 98.3%, VD: 21.5%, GPUClock: 1966MHz, VEClock: 1816MHz
frame type IDR    595
frame type I      595,  avgQP  20.00,  total size   39.44 MB
frame type P    28519,  avgQP  23.00,  total size  471.93 MB
frame type B   113478,  avgQP  25.00,  total size  587.45 MB
```

but when I try to play it in either PotPlayer or VLC it says there is no video track or it just doesn't play at all.
MediaInfo also doesn't show any video, audio, or subtitle tracks either, just the name of the file and the file size. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Switching `--avhw` to `--avsw` solved the problem.